# what is the mistake in this code the question says to find the no. of elements less than the current element?

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> smallerNumbersThanCurrent(vector<int>& nums) { 
    vector<int> ans;
    int k;
    if(nums.empty())
    {
          return ans;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    {
        k=0;
        for(int j=i+1;j<nums.size();j++)
        {
           if(nums[i]>nums[j])
                 k++;
        }
        ans.push_back(k);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Your input   [8,1,2,2,3]

Output       [4,0,0,0,0]

Expected     [4,0,1,1,3]

please help me with the code why the output is not correct.
if I enter the input in decreasing order then the output is correct.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: `for(int j=i+1;j<nums.size();j++)` -> `for(int j=0;j<nums.size();j++)`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you only compare the current element to the remaining values that come *afterwards* in the array, not to *all* the other elements in the array (i.e., also the ones *before*). Hence, backwards the output is correct. Best regards!